# How can I rewrite this query so as to avoid the error: You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: sql, mysql

```
update websites set master = 2 where url = select url from websites where id = 12;
```

Apparently mysql won't allow you to run a select query on table you're updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it into a derived table. [This gets materialised into a temp table and gets around the restriction](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/).

```
update websites
set    master = 2
where  url in (select url
               from   (select url
                       from   websites
                       where  id = 12) t);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update websites set master = 2 where url in (select w2.url from websites w2 where w2.id = 12);
```

Comment: k, how about 

update websites w, websites w2 set w2.master = 2 where w.url = w2.url and w2.id = 12);